Why generics are not working in this case?
I am kinda a newbie with TypeScript, and I am using it on a real project along with React.
I saw a post where the writter indicates two ways of declare conditional props in React using Typescript.
The writer indicates two ways to declare conditional props in React using TypeScript.
I tried the solution using generics (because I want to approach it that way), and I did not get TypeScript warning me about the type that should be the prop called "level" after checking if the authenticated prop was true.
Here's the code:
type Props<T extends boolean> = {   
  authenticated: T;   
  level: T extends true ? 'basic' | 'admin' : 'guest'
}; 

const User = <T extends boolean>(props: Props<T>) => { 
  if (props.authenticated) { 
    return <>Profile ({props.level})</>; } 
  return <>{props.level}</> 
};

Basically, in that case, I thought that Typescript should have known that the type of the level prop was 'basic' or 'admin', but after hovering the props.level, the result was: (property) level: T extends true ? "basic" | "admin" : "guest". So, Typescript didn't know the type. Maybe I am wrong, and I am not differentiating between runtime and compile time (where Typescript acts).
This is a playground of the code as well: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCmATzCTgAUcwBnAHgBU4kAPGJAHYATFnABGECABtUAgHxwAvHADecdRXUoArjAAWgmMDQp+QgFxwOAbnVxNcGQDckUy1179homFG30AfgIxFBZjfDgAHwIUIRBgAQjLfABzfxYYMnIAX1sKCjQIAQy4AFUWJCglOE5uPkERcUkZFHkACjBmFksmCFZOOQBKJQU1B2BMOA6ugDodfUNjUyQhYbHyOzgiGG0oARq5XsxgGSmVTr6WGedXbMG2AHo5W2z7Da2kHb2D89mbqWyjwUFFyQA

Why would you expect a warning? Your usage of level in both cases is valid, it's a string unless if I am missing your point

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't get it, why would you expect a warning in this code? Where exactly is the problem?  Please [edit] to clarify the issue and to provide a [mre] where the problem is obvious and apparent to anyone who copies and pastes the code into their own IDE.

Thanks all for your response!
Finally, I found an approach which fits a little bit better with my case. I decided to use distributive conditional types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types
This is the result code:
 type Props<T extends boolean> = T extends unknown ? {   
      authenticated: T;   
      level: T extends true ? 'basic' | 'admin' : 'guest'
    } : never; 

const User = <T extends boolean>(props: Props<T>) => { 
  if (props.authenticated) { 
    return <>Profile ({props.level})</>; } 
  return <>{props.level}</> 
};

Now Typescript knows that when authenticated is true the level prop can be only basic or admin
I approached this way thanks to this answer: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/58224#issuecomment-2060905027
This is a playground of the code with the solution: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOABRzAGcAeAFTiQA8YkA7ACZM4AIwgQANqj4A+OAF44Hbr0HCArnwDWfCAHc+cAPxwA3nAukLKdTAAW-GMDQpeAgFxKA3BbhW4UgBuSBKeyjz8QnAwUOq0JvgiKEzO+HAAPgQoAiDAfGme+ADmcUwwZAC+cJ58SMFQPuRoEHxlcACqTEhQCnDsnBFqouJSKLIAFGCMTJ4MEMzsMgCUCnLm-sCYcJPTAHQ29o7OrkgCK+u+cEQw6lCGLDJzmMBS26ZT80y7QSEVSywAehkPiq-mut3uMneex+EgqgLkpAqXiAA

This is what you have now:
type Props<T extends boolean> = {   
  authenticated: T;   
  level: T extends true ? 'basic' | 'admin' : 'guest'
}; 

const User = <T extends boolean>(props: Props<T>) => { 
  return props.level 
}

const guestUser = User({ authenticated: false, level: 'guest' }); // guest
const basicUser = User({ authenticated: true, level: 'basic' });  // basic
const adminUser = User({ authenticated: true, level: 'admin' });  // admin

console.log(guestUser);
console.log(basicUser);
console.log(adminUser);

You should define two different user types and then create a discriminated union:
type AuthenticatedUser = {
  authenticated: true;
  level: 'basic' | 'admin';
};

type GuestUser = {
  authenticated: false;
};

type UserProps = AuthenticatedUser | GuestUser;

const User = <T extends UserProps>(props: T) => {
  return 'level' in props ? props.level : 'guest';
}

const guestUser = User({ authenticated: false }); // guest
const basicUser = User({ authenticated: true, level: 'basic' });  // basic
const adminUser = User({ authenticated: true, level: 'admin' });  // admin

Here is how you can apply the types above to your component:
type AuthenticatedUser = {
  authenticated: true;
  level: 'basic' | 'admin';
};

type GuestUser = {
  authenticated: false;
};

type UserProps = AuthenticatedUser | GuestUser;

const User = <T extends UserProps>(props: T) => {
  if (!props.authenticated) {
    return <>Guest</> 
  }
  return <>Profile ({props.level})</>; } 
}


Thanks for your answer. I also considered this solution, using discriminated union types as you did. However, is there any other solution using generics? I don't want to retype the props multiple times. The example I showed is a simplified version; my case is longer because I am using objects, etc. But if I can get this solution working, I will be able to apply it to my case
